# The best approach to show div content with jQuery depending on which navbar link is 'active'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So, I have build a simple page with bootstrap, which has two links on it. The idea is that when a one of them is clicked a different some content contained in a `div` must be shown.

This is one of the divs(the other one follows the same pattern) :

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li id = "productsActive" **class="active"**><a href="#">
                    PRODUCTS
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li id = "usersActive"><a href="#">
                    USERS
                </a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

<div id = "products">
<input id="txtProductName" type="text" placeholder="productname">
<input id="txtProductPrice" type="text" placeholder="product price">
<button id="btnAddProduct">Add product</button>
<input id="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="search">




    <div class="bs-example" data-example-id="hoverable-table">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>product Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>


            <tbody id="lblProducts">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Then, when the users link is clicked I am giving it's

in the navbar an `active` status.
I am doing this with this code :

```
$(".nav a").on("click", function(){
            $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        });
```

And here all my problems start.

I am unable to make so that the content for `users` is shown when the users `<li>` is `active` and the same for `products` when it's clicked instead of suers.

```
if($('#productsActive').hasClass('active')){
            console.log("xxx");
             $('#products').hide();
             $('#users').show();//users is set is always huidde with the hide() function.

         }
```

All I get is a mess of everything displayed silumtaneously without being able to control the content display by clicking on the `links`.

Please help.
Any input will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Make a fiddle so others can debug it easily.

Comment: If you will add fiddle or any snippets it will be issuer to identify you issue..

Comment: That if-statement needs an event to fire. Easiest solution would be to just move the block inside of the onclick function you've set up. Now if you want to show the corresponding content when there hasn't been any action yet (ie the class was added server-side), move the block to fire on $(document).ready.